# Deleting entry only if there is no more reference to other table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

i have three tables :

Parent:
Table A:

```
id tab_b tab_c
1  b1    c1
2  b1    c2
```

two child tables:
Table b:

```
id name
b1 ABC
FOREIN KEY (id) REFERENCES table A (tab_b) ON DELETTE CASCADE
```

Table c:

```
id name
c1 DEF
c2 GHI
FOREIN KEY (id) REFERENCES table A (tab_c) ON DELETTE CASCADE
```

if i want to delete c2 in Table c, only the entry c2 in Table C and the entry 2 in Table A should be deleted. b1 should only be deleted if there are no more entries with reference to it. Actually the entry in Table b will be deleted too. (i tried it with RESTRICT too, but there are nothing will be deleted). Is there a possibility to do it with ON DELETE/ ON UPDATE  and CASCADE / RESTRICT?

or have i to this proggrammicly in php?

i hope it´s clear what i want.

thanks in advance

Comment: `ON DELETE CASCADE` is designed to work going from parent to children, not the other way around.  So if you delete a record in A then it will also remove all children records.  Maybe you have a design problem.

Comment: I think you have mixed up your relations. Tables b and c look like the parent table, and table a looks like the child table because the id fields in tables b and c are part of the relationship. Therefore the fks should point from table a to tables b and c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using FKs, you can define "ON DELETE" with "CASCADE", "RESTRICT" or "SET NULL". When deleting an entry, which is a FK in other entries, "CASCADE" will delete them, "SET NULL" will set the FK to "NULL" and "RESTRICT" will stop the entire process.

What you want is the opposite as far as I understand. If you have three tables "A", "B" and "C" where "A" contains "n-n" references, you have to be tricky. Something like:

```
DELETE IGNORE  B, C
FROM    B
INNER JOIN  A
    ON      A.tab_b = B.id
INNER JOIN  C
    ON      A.tab_c = C.id
WHERE       c.id = ?;
```

If this doesn't work, set "ON DELETE CASCADE" in "A", delete the items in "C" manually and use an "AFTER DELETE TRIGGER" to take care of "B".